# Representing a graph where nodes are also weights

Tags: graph

Consider a graph that has weights on each of its nodes instead of between two nodes. Therefore the cost of traveling to a node would be the weight of that node.

1- How can we represent this graph?

2- Is there a minimum spanning path algorithm for this type of graph (or could we modify an existing algorithm)?

For example, consider a matrix. What path, when traveling from a certain number to another, would produce a minimum sum? (Keep in mind the graph must be directed)

Answer (score 1):

1. if one don't want to adjust existing algorithms and use edge oriented approaches, one could transform node weights to edge weights. For every incoming edge of node v, one would save the weight of v to the edge. Thats the representation.
2. well, with the approach of 1. this is now easy to do with well known algorithms like MST.

You could also represent the graph as wished and hold the weight at the node. The algorithm simply didn't use `Weight w = edge.weight();` it would use `Weight w = edge.target().weight()`
simply done. no big adjustments are necessary.

if you have to use adjacency matrix, you need a second array with node weights and in adjacency matrix are just 0 - for no edge or 1 - for an edge.

hope that helped